# sql query to extract rows

Tags: mysql, sql

table:

```
id    user_id    guessed_id    result
1219  27         4             Y
1357  20         4             Y
2     3          5             N
9     20         5             N
1392  20         11            Y
1618  27         11            N
2471  20         25            Y
```

I would like to build a query that fetches only the guessed_ids that have exactly 2 result with the value Y.

In the above rows the query should return:

```
4
```

since the rows containing the guessed_id 4 have both Y in the column result.

guessed_id 5 should not be returned since it contains 2 N

11 should not be returned since it has a N

25 should not be returned since it has only one Y

I am using mysql DBMS.

Comment: @illinoistim problem is solved by the answer from answer below

Comment: My point was not to give you a fish, but to teach you how to fish, or in this case, write SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` will do what you want, just count the number of `Y`'s and return the `guessed_id`s where the count is 2;

```
SELECT guessed_id
FROM myTable
WHERE result='Y'
GROUP BY guessed_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd9a6/2).

I'm not sure from your example whether any `N` results are allowed for a hit, I assumed they're not relevant as long as there are exactly 2 rows with a `Y`.